# HTML5 and Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, html, css

After studying how to use objective C for the previous months I realise actually you can create an app using HTML 5, CSS 3 and JavaScript. Just want to know which method got more advantage than the other. Objective C or a combined usage of HTML 5, CSS 3 and JavaScript to create an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

You can create good HTML5 apps for iOS; absolutely. The HTML5 browser is very performant on newer iOS devices. That can mean that it is good for simple apps. However, if you want a native looking app (one that looks like it belongs on the platform) especially since iOS 7 released, you're going to have to go with native code. It will allow you to look native and have higher performing apps.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C as long as it's native to the iOS platform. Non-native apps are always quite sloppy and non-performant.